# GCC error message for ARM inline assembly: ARM register expected

Tags: c, gcc, arm, inline-assembly

Below is a piece of code I have written in C and in-line assembly to load some `short` values from the array `blk` to ARM `R` registers.

```
...
short *blk; 
... //blk memory allocation and initialization
short tmp0, tmp1, tmp2;
asm volatile (
"ldrh %[tmp0], [%0]\n\t"
"ldrh %[tmp1], [%1]\n\t"
"ldrh %[tmp2], [%2]\n\t"
: [tmp0] "=r" (tmp0), [tmp1] "=r" (tmp1), [tmp2] "=r" (tmp2)
: "m" (blk[0])  , "m" (blk[8]), "m" (blk[8*2])
: 
);
```

I am getting this error message from arm gcc 4.6

```
/tmp/ccDEBLCN.s:266: Error: ARM register expected -- `ldrh r3,[[r5,#0]]'
```

GCC complains about `ldrh %[tmp2], [%2]` line, but I don't see why. I took a look at `LDRH` instruction and it seems to me that my instruction template is right.

```
Load memory halfword [15:0] from register address + 5-bit immediate offset
LDRH <Rd>, [<Rn>, #<immed_5> * 2]
```

BTW this is the command I am using to compile this:

```
arm-none-linux-gnueabi-gcc -O2 -march=armv7-a -mthumb
```

Comment: Have you tried changing your "=r" to just "r"? This is the syntax I'm using.

Comment: It should be "=r" since `tmp` is output. Anyway, I get this error if I change it to "r".`193:3: error: output operand constraint lacks '=' 193:3: error: invalid lvalue in asm output 0`

Comment: Any thought on this? I have not been able to find a way to work around this.

Comment: If the code is only what you've shown, then the compiler is justly complaining that you're loading data into registers and not using it. ARM doesn't support memory-to-memory operations, so you need to LDR the data into registers, then STR the data back to memory.

Comment: No, I have removed many details from the code. But I don't understand your comment. From which message you concluded that I am not using data? Anyway, even if I am not using data, it should be a warning which clearly I don't get any warning message from compiler. Also, why are saying that I doing mem to mem operation? LDR clearly loads from an address (here `blk`, and "m" means a memory operand is allowed, with any kind of address that the machine supports) to a register (here `tmp`, and "r" means ARM core registers). Lastly, in this code I don't store any data. I'm sorry that I don't get you.

Comment: The error may be spurious. GCC has many bugs when it comes to intrinsics and inline assembly language. It also tries to eliminate "dead stores". Variables that are set, but never used. In the code above, you load 3 values into registers, but not variables. ARM is a load/store architecture - each instruction can only load or store data, not both. If the compiler were to accept the code you've written, it wouldn't do anything. It might load values into scratch registers, but the values would immediately be overwritten by the next instructions.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
asm (
"ldrh %[tmp0], %[ref0]\n\t"
"ldrh %[tmp1], %[ref1]\n\t"
"ldrh %[tmp2], %[ref2]\n\t"
: [tmp0] "=&r" (tmp0), [tmp1] "=&r" (tmp1), [tmp2] "=r" (tmp2)
: [ref0] "m" (blk[0])  , [ref1] "m" (blk[8]), [ref2] "m" (blk[8*2])
: 
);
```

Answer (score 1):

It looks like the compiler may be complaining that your code doesn't actually do anything. Is this what you really meant to do?

```
...
short *blk; 
... //blk memory allocation and initialization
short tmp0, tmp1, tmp2;
asm volatile (
"ldrh r0,[%[BLK]]\n\t"
"ldrh r1,[%[BLK], #8]\n\t"
"ldrh r2,[%[BLK], #16]\n\t"
"strh r0,[%tmp0] \n\t"
"strh r1,[%tmp1] \n\t"
"strh r2,[%tmp2] \n\t"
: [tmp0] "r" (tmp0), [tmp1] "r" (tmp1), [tmp2] "r" (tmp2), [BLK] "r" (blk)
: "r0", "r1", "r2"
: 
);
```

Comment: Yes, kinda. You use ro, r1, r2 as temporary registers. But I tried to load from memory (here blk array) directly into tmp0, tmp1, and tmp2 (tmp0, tmp1, and tmp2 themselves are stored in r registers). The other answer given here does direct loading into tmp variables. Thanks for your help though.

Comment: Let me rephrase what I meant. I meant to load from memory (blk here) into core registers (R registers here) and I wanted to refer to those registers as tmp0, tmp1, tmp2 variables in my C code.

Comment: I always assume that GCC will do the wrong thing and I'm usually right. I think you're asking too much of GCC to try to assign registers to local variables within inline asm and have it work. Inline asm is a special case (e.g. kludge) and GCC doesn't seem to treat it equally to the C code around it. From my experience, you need to have the asm code do all the work that needs to be done and assume it is distinct from the C code with the only exception being that you can read C variables, but the compiler thinks you're still not accessing those variables unless C uses them also.